# Checking duration of a marker-created subclip in Final Cut?

Tags: final-cut-pro, timecode

I just went through a long video clip in Final Cut 7, adding a marker as the speaker went into the next bullet point of his talk. I'm supposed to convert the clip into video podcasts less than 10 minutes apiece, either by posting each section individually or combining the shorter ones, so I needed to check how long he spent on each bullet point.

But when I click the disclosure arrow next to the video clip in the Browser to list the marker-generated subclips, there is no time listed next to them in the Duration column. I had to double-click each marker individually and drag the playhead to the end of the Viewer timeline for final cut to tell me how long each section was - not a big deal admittedly but I'm suspicious that I'm missing something. Is there a place in the Viewer or Browser windows I can get the length of each marker-generated subclip at a glance?

Answer (score 1):

**The reason you cant get the durations is because a marker is just reference to a point in time, not a time range.** This time around you will need to find the durations manually either by opening the clip or subtracting the time of the previous marker form the current one.

You can give markers durations, but not as effortlessly as just placing a single marker while watching through the video:

> Place a marker by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> then at the end time hit
>   <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, this will extend the duration of the
>   marker to wherever the playhead is.

[image: Marker with duration]